# Removing Spaces in text inside parentheses: Python

Tags: python, regex, text-processing

I am new to regex. How can I remove the spaces in the beginning and the end in this context.

a = "( a is a b  )"

I was trying

```
re.sub(r"\([(\s*\w+\s*)]*\)",r"",a)
```

But I managed to write some for the pattern but for the replacement I couldn't get any idea. I am not sure, if it is correct for the pattern as well. Need your kind support. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with two substitutions. There may be a better way.

```
import re

a = "( a is a b )"

print(re.sub('\(\s+', '(', re.sub('\s+\)', ')', a)))
```

**Output:**

```
(a is a b)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think using **lookahead**/**lookbehind** is a better way in your case. In this pattern, it is checking if there is parentheses before or after spaces. (You can read details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973436/regex-lookahead-lookbehind-and-atomic-groups)). You can also read explanations for this regex pattern [here](https://regex101.com/r/PtK0oo/1)

```py
pattern = r"\s(?=\))|(?<=\()\s"
s = 'a = ( a is b )'
result = re.sub(pattern, '', s)
```

**Output:**

```py
a = (a is b)
```